# Dynamic Fields Django Quiz App

Tags: django, forms

I am really stuck at the moment. I have searched on here, tutorials, and the documentation. I am trying to dynamically create a specific field. For example, a user can chose to have anywhere from 2-6 answers in a multiple choice quiz. However, the tutorials I've followed to seem to be of no help and I have a hard time understanding the documentation.

I got very strange answers when using inline formsets.

here is my form and model code as it stands.

```
class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['title', 'answerA', 'answerB', 'answerC', 'answerD', 'difficulty_level', 'correctAnswer']

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=1500)
    answerA = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    answerB = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    answerC = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    answerD = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    difficulty_level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Quiz.DIFFICULTY_LEVELS)
    # score = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    correctAnswer = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

class Quiz(models.Model):

    quizID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default = '')
    answerA = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    answerB = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    answerC = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    answerD = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    # score = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    correctAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    DIFFICULTY_LEVELS = (
        ('Beginner', '1'),
        ('Intermediate', '2'),
        ('Advanced', '3'),
    )
    difficulty_level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVELS, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```